# Submit form after form load is blank

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I make index.php like this:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#sload").load('save1.php',function(forma){
    $(".csave").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {       
                alert(data);
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
});
});
</script>
<a href="#" class="csave">SAVE</a>
<div id="sload"></div>
```

save1.php like this :

```
<table>
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="input1.php">
    <tr>    
        <td>Date</td><td>:</td><td><input name="date" id="date"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>Location</td><td>:</td><td><input name="location" id="location" /></td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

and input1.php

```
<? session_start();
include "db.php";
$date=$_POST['date'];
$location=$_POST['location'];

mysql_query("insert into hal (date,location) values ('$date','$location')");
?>
```

after I click SAVE not an error, but the database is stored in an empty field. Submit form after form load is blank

Thanks.

Comment: Use var_dump($_POST) to see what's inside this array

Comment: var_dump($_POST) in Jquery function or in php? with example please?

Comment: In your input1.php do die(var_dump($_POST)) and after clicking SAVE check the ajax response via chrome dev console or firebug or something like that.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the logic of loading and saving like this:

Here's an example (based on your code) as a single page script **test.php**:

```
<?php

// Load Form
if (isset($_GET['loadForm']))
{
    exit('<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="test.php">
    <table>
        <tr>    
            <td>Date</td><td>:</td><td><input name="date" id="date"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Location</td><td>:</td><td><input name="location" id="location" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>');
}

// Handle Form Save
if (count($_POST) > 0)
{
    // TODO
    exit('got form data: '. print_r($_POST, true));
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// When Page Loads
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Load Form
    $('#sload').load('test.php?loadForm');

    // Handle Save Click
    $('.csave').click(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {       
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>

<a href="#" class="csave">SAVE</a>
<div id="sload"></div>
```

When I click save, this is what the output is:

[image]

To complete this code, add the db row inserting code where it says `TODO`. Hope this helps.

---

**Update**

Here's the split version:

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

// When Page Loads
$(document).ready(function()
{
    // Load Form
    $('#sload').load('save1.php');

    // Handle Save Click
    $('.csave').click(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $('#form1').attr('action'),
            data: $('#form1').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {       
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    });
});

</script>

<a href="#" class="csave">SAVE</a>
<div id="sload"></div>
```

**save1.php**

```
<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="input1.php">
<table>
    <tr>    
        <td>Date</td><td>:</td><td><input name="date" id="date"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>    
        <td>Location</td><td>:</td><td><input name="location" id="location" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**input1.php**

```
<?php

session_start(); // what's this for? you aren't using session on this file

// this is not safe! use mysqli or pdo and escape post values!!!
include "db.php";
$date=$_POST['date'];
$location=$_POST['location'];

mysql_query("insert into hal (date,location) values ('$date','$location')");

?>
```

Comment: BTW `mysql_*` library is deprecated. Please use `PDO` or `MySQLi`. Also, you need to escape the posted form field values; as you are open to SQL Injection now...

Comment: If the single page example is confusing, let me know, I can split it up like the way you have it.

Comment: please split into 3 files as I needed, thanks before.

Comment: please email it into tijobae@gmail.com, happy to meet you Latheesan Kanes